# Multiboot system grub issues - edited - modified

Tags: grub

EDIT /  MODIFY
After receiving long replay basically stating
"what you see in grub is bogus "
I have given up on this problem - in my opinion I have to delete MAJORITY of the Ubuntu entries and hope my PC will still function.

I would like to get an answer for this question.
(It may be repost )

My bogus "grub" is telling me I have Ubuntu 5.15.0.50 GENERIC installed. None of the OS options and their "advanced options" indicate that such generic can be booted  from.
Since my currently "limping along" 22.04.1 generic is  5.13.0.46 and is slowly getting worse,  I like to  at lest try 5.15.0.50.

Any reasonable solution's on how?  ( to run 5.15.0.50) - clean load from ISO is NOT REASONABLE - I value my C++ code more than working OS - would be greatly appreciated.

Please NO "switch to Linux flavor of the month".

Cheers.

This is multi-question post.

1. My multiboot system - all Ubuntu, no Windows - loads (and runs - used "df" ) from `/dev/sde14`, however the "grub" menu shows it is actually loading from `/dev/sdd3`.
   How is this possible?
2. I like to clean up unused / failing to load OS partitions. The "grub" menu shows `dev/sde31`, however "gparted" does not  show such partition.
   What file can I edit to remove this item from "grub" menu manually?

```
q5@q5-desktop:~$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0     7:0    0   5.2M  1 loop  /snap/bluez/334
loop1     7:1    0     4K  1 loop  /snap/bare/5
loop2     7:2    0   5.2M  1 loop  /snap/bluez/302
loop3     7:3    0 114.9M  1 loop  /snap/core/13741
loop4     7:4    0   115M  1 loop  /snap/core/13886
loop5     7:5    0  55.6M  1 loop  /snap/core18/2560
loop6     7:6    0  55.6M  1 loop  /snap/core18/2566
loop7     7:7    0    62M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1611
loop8     7:8    0  63.2M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1623
loop9     7:9    0  86.8M  1 loop  /snap/crossover/16
loop10    7:10   0 238.1M  1 loop  /snap/firefox/1918
loop11    7:11   0 236.8M  1 loop  /snap/firefox/1943
loop12    7:12   0 346.3M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115
loop13    7:13   0 164.8M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
loop14    7:14   0 346.3M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
loop15    7:15   0  91.7M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop16    7:16   0  81.3M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop17    7:17   0 107.5M  1 loop  /snap/logs/13
loop18    7:18   0  45.9M  1 loop  /snap/snap-store/592
loop19    7:19   0  45.9M  1 loop  /snap/snap-store/599
sda       8:0    1 465.8G  0 disk  
└─sda1    8:1    1 465.8G  0 part  
sdb       8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk  
├─sdb1    8:17   0   512M  0 part  
├─sdb2    8:18   0    17G  0 part  
├─sdb3    8:19   0  41.9G  0 part  
├─sdb4    8:20   0 195.3G  0 part  
│ └─md127
│         9:127  0 390.4G  0 raid5 /mnt/md127
│                                  /mnt/MDI_RAID_5
├─sdb6    8:22   0  41.3G  0 part  
├─sdb7    8:23   0  97.7G  0 part  
├─sdb8    8:24   0  97.7G  0 part  
├─sdb9    8:25   0   977M  0 part  
├─sdb10   8:26   0    98G  0 part  
├─sdb12   8:28   0 147.2G  0 part  
├─sdb14   8:30   0  38.1G  0 part  
├─sdb15   8:31   0  97.7G  0 part  
├─sdb16 259:2    0  61.7G  0 part  
├─sdb17 259:3    0 195.3G  0 part  
│ └─md127
│         9:127  0 390.4G  0 raid5 /mnt/md127
│                                  /mnt/MDI_RAID_5
├─sdb18 259:4    0 146.5G  0 part  
├─sdb26 259:5    0   9.9G  0 part  
└─sdb30 259:6    0  96.8G  0 part  
sdc       8:32   0 298.1G  0 disk  
├─sdc1    8:33   0   512M  0 part  
├─sdc3    8:35   0  19.5G  0 part  
├─sdc5    8:37   0     4G  0 part  
├─sdc6    8:38   0     7G  0 part  
├─sdc7    8:39   0  24.9G  0 part  
├─sdc8    8:40   0    35G  0 part  
├─sdc16 259:0    0     7G  0 part  
└─sdc17 259:1    0  79.6G  0 part  
sdd       8:48   0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sdd1    8:49   0 147.2G  0 part  
├─sdd4    8:52   0 147.2G  0 part  
├─sdd5    8:53   0 147.2G  0 part  
├─sdd6    8:54   0 147.2G  0 part  
└─sdd7    8:55   0 146.7G  0 part  
sde       8:64   0   2.7T  0 disk  
├─sde1    8:65   0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sde2    8:66   0 301.6G  0 part  /media/q5/7309e060-4c31-462d-89e2-e2a2d9d051571
├─sde3    8:67   0  96.8G  0 part  /media/q5/eaf6611c-a53c-4b45-9c2c-7bb0f57d1b956
├─sde4    8:68   0     5G  0 part  /media/q5/eaf6611c-a53c-4b45-9c2c-7bb0f57d1b955
├─sde5    8:69   0 188.6G  0 part  /media/q5/eaf6611c-a53c-4b45-9c2c-7bb0f57d1b954
├─sde7    8:71   0 212.3G  0 part  /media/q5/TEMP+PHOTOS1
├─sde8    8:72   0     1M  0 part  
├─sde9    8:73   0  96.8G  0 part  /media/q5/272a5fa3-385b-46c5-9107-109ea3b7fd0c1
├─sde10   8:74   0  33.6G  0 part  /media/q5/0d1ba4f5-9db9-491b-a83e-03670b2913c6
├─sde11   8:75   0     7G  0 part  /media/q5/07fb0647-7d13-44da-bf01-6f4a48f2c8a61
├─sde14   8:78   0 324.2G  0 part  /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
│                                  /
├─sde16 259:7    0 147.2G  0 part  /media/q5/1T_NEW_COPY
├─sde17 259:8    0 114.5G  0 part  
├─sde18 259:9    0 195.3G  0 part  
│ └─md127
│         9:127  0 390.4G  0 raid5 /mnt/md127
│                                  /mnt/MDI_RAID_5
├─sde19 259:10   0 116.6G  0 part  /media/q5/07fb0647-7d13-44da-bf01-6f4a48f2c8a6
├─sde20 259:11   0  96.8G  0 part  /media/q5/eaf6611c-a53c-4b45-9c2c-7bb0f57d1b957
├─sde21 259:12   0 224.9G  0 part  /media/q5/04ab946c-a6e6-4e56-b952-bbd652caf6111
└─sde22 259:13   0    14G  0 part  /media/q5/0537ec3b-5c68-4951-90a5-536ad44f2cbd1
sdf       8:80   1     0B  0 disk  
sdg       8:96   1     0B  0 disk  
sdh       8:112  1     0B  0 disk  
sdi       8:128  1     0B  0 disk  
sdj       8:144  1  14.4G  0 disk  
├─sdj1    8:145  1   512M  0 part  
└─sdj2    8:146  1  13.9G  0 part  /media/q5/4835fa9c-77a4-490a-94bf-80f40b432366
sdk       8:160  0 149.1G  0 disk  
└─sdk1    8:161  0   149G  0 part  /media/q5/MDI
q5@q5-desktop:~$
```

POSTED As requested

```
q5@q5-desktop:~$  sudo efibootmgr -v 
[sudo] password for q5: 
BootCurrent: 0005
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0005,0000,0006,0009,000C,000D,000E,000F,000B,0002
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,2051a2c4-274c-4564-8d21-f272138c9284,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0002  USB   BBS(USB,,0x0)..GO..NO........].e.M. .B.a.y. .R.e.a.d.e.r. .1...0.0....................A...................................$..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.9.2.0.3.1.1.1........BO..NO........e.e.M. .B.a.y. .R.e.a.d.e.r. .1...0.1....................A...........................................$..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.9.2.0.3.1.1.1........BO..NO........e.e.M. .B.a.y. .R.e.a.d.e.r. .1...0.2....................A...........................................$..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.9.2.0.3.1.1.1........BO..NO{.......Y.S.e.a.g.a.t.e....................A.............................&..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.N.A.8.3.3.B.D.C........BO..NO.........K.i.n.g.s.t.o.n.D.a.t.a.T.r.a.v.e.l.e.r. .3...0.P.M.A.P....................A...................................F..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.6.C.6.2.6.D.7.C.2.7.E.6.B.1.2.1.6.9.2.4.0.0.6.E........BO..NO........g.W.D.C. .W.D.1.6.0.0.A.B.-.2.2.D.Y.A.0....................A......................................Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.7.D.1.6.0.0.A.B.5.2.2.D........BO..NO........e.e.M. .B.a.y. .R.e.a.d.e.r. .1...0.3....................A...........................................$..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.9.2.0.3.1.1.1........BO..NO........o.S.e.a.g.a.t.e. .B.U.P. .U.l.t.r.a. .T.o.u.c.h. .0.0.0.4....................A...................................6..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.N.A.B.1.3.3.H.H........BO
Boot0005* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,0621e243-4a24-4e6d-bdbb-cd02425977f8,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)..BO
Boot0006* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)..GO..NO........u.S.T.3.3.2.0.4.1.8.A.S....................A.................................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . . . . . . . . . .V.6.P.M.D.L.P.Z........BO..NO........u.H.i.t.a.c.h.i. .H.D.S.7.2.1.0.1.0.C.L.A.3.3.2....................A.................................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . . . .P.J.9.6.0.4.D.H.T.2.G.1.F.P........BO..NO........o.W.D.C. .W.D.5.0.0.0.A.A.K.S.-.7.5.V.0.A.0....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . .W. .-.D.C.W.W.A.8.F.5.3.6.8.8.8........BO..NO........o.W.D.C. .W.D.2.0.E.Z.A.Z.-.0.0.G.G.J.B.0....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . .W. .-.D.X.W.2.K.9.A.1.0.4.L.P.H........BO
Boot0009* UEFI: Seagate PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/USB(1,0)/USB(3,0)/HD(1,GPT,bdea077f-9c43-4715-93c9-25136563c691,0x800,0x100000)..BO
Boot000B  ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,6854ec75-d77f-4e3e-b98c-fd028c46e45b,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)..BO
Boot000C* UEFI: KingstonDataTraveler 3.0PMAP    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/USB(1,0)/USB(4,0)/USB(5,0)/HD(1,GPT,2051a2c4-274c-4564-8d21-f272138c9284,0x800,0x100000)..BO
Boot000D* UEFI: Seagate BUP Ultra Touch 0004    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/USB(1,0)/USB(1,0)/USB(4,0)/HD(1,GPT,7149cebc-a872-4fa7-bf45-e75ea1672895,0xffff,0xefff1)..BO
Boot000E* UEFI: Seagate BUP Ultra Touch 0004    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/USB(1,0)/USB(1,0)/USB(4,0)/HD(10,GPT,66537b42-4255-4eef-886f-7f0d54024f1f,0x803c8000,0x39fbc000)..BO
Boot000F* UEFI: Seagate BUP Ultra Touch 0004    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/USB(1,0)/USB(1,0)/USB(4,0)/HD(12,GPT,eaa6938b-2fda-41b8-a307-6eaa95e594e4,0xba384000,0x3a98000)..BO
q5@q5-desktop:~$
```

Comment: What does (and runs - used "df") mean?

Comment: If you want to see lots of details on boot configuration run the Summary report from Boot-Repair. I regularly run it and save a copy in /home, so backed up. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I have run / installed suggested  Boot_repair Received thisHit:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/lubuntu-dev/backports/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done                              
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be

Comment: I do appreciate editing my post , however, I did not ask for a lecture in English composition, I clearly asked for hep fixing Ubuntu  grub issue. Editing my post is superfluous and not relevant to my post.

Comment: I tun "df": to verify which partition was actually used to root.

Comment: I  run "update-grub" regularly and the problem persist.

Comment: It is not a matter  how many Ubuntu are installed, it is a matter  "grub" loading from  one partition and OS actually  running from another one.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. How is this possible?

Any text in the GRUB boot menu items is just text. It has no direct relationship to any Linux devices - because while GRUB runs, Linux devices **do not exist yet**. And passing the list of disks/partitions/bootable OSs from the firmware/bootloader to the kernel won't necessarily help either: **there is no general guarantee that the Linux kernel will detect the disks in the same order as your firmware does.**

On a UEFI system like yours probably is (by the presence of the `/boot/efi` filesystem), the firmware loads the bootloader based on the information in UEFI NVRAM variables. You could view them with `sudo efibootmgr -v`. Those variables can identify the EFI System Partition (ESP for short) and the file within it to boot in several ways, but the most common is probably using a PARTUUID and a Windows-style pathname.

Once the firmware has loaded the bootloader, the bootloader can basically do anything it wants. Normally GRUB will read a configuration file that will tell it what to do and what kind of menu to show. The location of that configuration file can be a) embedded within the `grubx64.efi` file, or b) specified indirectly by a mini-`grub.cfg` located in the same directory the `grubx64.efi` file is in.

Internally, GRUB uses disk and partition identifiers like `(hd0,gpt1)`. Any references to `/dev/sd*` are meaningless to GRUB at boot time. If the boot menu items include any Linux device names, they are **historical information** at best, and **outright guesses** at worst. Since GRUB has only a fraction of the capabilities of the Linux kernel and initramfs, the best it can do is document how the Linux device names existed when the GRUB configuration was being created, nothing more.

If you have executed Boot_repair's suggested repair action, then it has probably added a new UEFI boot variable that invokes a version of GRUB installed by Boot_repair, using a configuration file that was created by Boot_repair. Since that effectively overrides all your distributions' GRUB instances, it might be helpful when you need to get your system booting again... but since the menu generated by Boot_repair won't necessarily get updated as your installed OSs receive kernel updates, such a Boot_repair-generated GRUB configuration should be treated not as a permanent solution, but as a **temporary workaround** to allow you to decide which of your multi-boot OSs should manage the primary bootloader and how the other OSs/bootloaders should be coupled to the primary one.

Having said that, "`grub` loading from one partition and OS actually running from another one" can actually be a completely normal situation:

- on UEFI systems, the firmware (or the Secure Boot shim) loads GRUB from the ESP (on Debian/Ubuntu, normally a separate filesystem mounted at `/boot/efi`)
- GRUB reads its configuration from one or more filesystem locations (normally `/boot/grub` which may be part of the Linux root filesystem or a separate `/boot` filesystem, but more esoteric configurations are certainly possible)
- the GRUB configuration dictates where GRUB reads the kernel and initramfs files, and which kernel boot parameters it provides to the kernel (normally the kernel and initramfs files are at `/boot`, but with custom GRUB configuration, they could be on any filesystem that can be supported by GRUB and/or the system firmware).
- ultimately, the contents of the initramfs will dictate which filesystem gets mounted as the Linux root filesystem (most distributions' initramfs implementations respect the kernel boot option `root=`, but it would be possible to entirely ignore it and do whatever the initramfs is configured to do)

### 2. What file can I edit to remove this item from "grub" menu manually?

We cannot possibly know that, since you haven't provided us the necessary information to figure that out. However, I can give you some pointers on how to figure it out yourself.

First, since you apparently have an UEFI system, you are in luck. On a BIOS-boot system, this would be trickier.

Start with `sudo efibootmgr -v`. The `BootCurrent: NNNN` line will identify the corresponding `BootNNNN` boot variable that was used by the system to get to the current state. The `BootNNNN` line can have several forms, but it will probably contain the PARTUUID of the ESP where the bootloader file was loaded from, and the pathname of the bootloader file, relative to the root of the ESP filesystem, Microsoft-style. You can view the PARTUUIDs of your partitions with `lsblk -o +partuuid`, no `sudo` required.

If the bootloader file is `shimx64.efi`, it will load `grubx64.efi` from the same directory the shim was located in. If the bootloader file is `grubx64.efi`, it's loaded directly without the Secure Boot shim. If there is a `grub.cfg` file in the same directory of the ESP, read it: in most cases, it is either the actual GRUB configuration, or a mini-configuration that just tells GRUB where the real configuration file is, probably using a filesystem UUID and a pathname. Use `lsblk -o +uuid` to view filesystem UUIDs of your filesystems.

However, it is possible that your GRUB has the configuration file pathname embedded within the `grubx64.efi` binary and pointing to some non-obvious location. In that case, `strings grubx64.efi | grep -B 1 '^sbat,1,SBAT Version' | head -1` just might provide a clue; however, this is not guaranteed to work as reliably finding the initial configuration file path from within the GRUB binary would require parsing binary data structures.

---

### 3. From the `efibootmgr -v` output

Based on the `efibootmgr -v` output, your system may currently have (or may have had) three separate GRUB instances, and all of them are named `ubuntu`, so there is probably no way to tell them apart in BIOS boot order menus.

The `BootCurrent: 0005` indicates that the system is currently booted up using the `Boot0005` entry:

```
Boot0005* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,0621e243-4a24-4e6d-bdbb-cd02425977f8,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)..BO
```

From here, we can see that the unique PARTUUID of the EFI System Partition that contains the bootloader is `0621e243-4a24-4e6d-bdbb-cd02425977f8`, and that it is probably the first partition on its GPT-partitioned disk (`HD(1,GPT...`). Run `lsblk -o +partuuid | grep -i 0621e243-4a24-4e6d-bdbb-cd02425977f8`, and you'll identify the disk that contains the active bootloader.

If that is *not* the disk that is mounted as `/boot/efi` in your current running instance of Ubuntu, then my theory was correct and you are currently booting using the GRUB of some other Ubuntu instance, using the GRUB configuration file that was generated when `sudo update-grub` was last executed in *that* OS instance. Booting into that OS instance, running `sudo update-grub` there, and then booting back into your current OS would most likely cause `os-prober` to recognize that the currently-running Ubuntu instance now has the 5.15.0-50 kernel, and update the boot menu accordingly.

However, if the currently running Ubuntu instance is your "primary" one, you might instead want to make its bootloader the primary one. To do that, you would have to check the PARTUUID of your current `/boot/efi` filesystem:

```
lsblk -o +partuuid |grep /boot/efi
```

Tind the `BootNNNN` line in the `sudo efibootmgr -v` output that contains that PARTUUID. Then use `sudo efibootmgr --bootorder NNNN,0005,0000,006,0009,000C,000D,000E,000F,000B,0002` where NNNN matches the number on the `BootNNNN` line that contains the PARTUUID of your current `/boot/efi`.

This is a one-time operation, and if successful, `sudo update-grub` in this Ubuntu instance should update the active bootloader normally, and any kernel updates should automatically become visible in the GRUB boot menu again. However, the **other** Ubuntu instance will lose its role as "primary maintainer of the boot menu", and any kernel updates to *that* Ubuntu instance will only be bootable after `sudo update-grub` is run in the *current* Ubuntu instance.

After this change, you may see that the GRUB boot menu might now be quite different, as the `sudo update-grub` will run `os-prober` to rebuild the list of other bootable OS instances. This might well solve the problem of you seeing non-existent partitions in the GRUB menus; however, if the "ghost" instances still persist, they should be findable in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` of your current Ubuntu instance, and you might choose to customize it or the `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` script to reduce the number of listed OS instances.

Once you've successfully made the GRUB instance that matches your primary OS as your primary bootloader (using the instructions above) *and have tested that it works to your satisfaction*, then you might consider removing the extra `BootNNNN` entries from the firmware boot variables, using `sudo efibootmgr --delete-bootnum -b NNNN`. That will at least minimize confusion in in your firmware boot order menus ("BIOS settings").

Comment: I try to post results of sudo efibootmgr -v , got An error occurred submitting the edit.

Comment: results of sudo efibootmgr -v  added  to original post Oct 15